# How to bind to-many relationship to the tableview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a program with a database:

Question <->> Answer

The relationship is to-many. The answer contains two fields: value (yes or no) and date (which is set to now when you create a view)

I've created a window in IB. In the table, first column displays the questions using ArrayController, the second includes checkboxes connected to the most recent Answer. I do not know how to use bindings to select particular answers from database with the right date. Is there a way to pass a date value from the code to IB? I tried to use two separate ArrayControllers, but I do not know how to identify relevant objects with the Answers connected with Questions to the second one. Maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store all data in one array and access questions, answers and answer dates by key? Or you can create an intermediate structure for that.